# How a thread-safe program may contain classes that are not thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I just started reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/), from the page 17:

> We’ve used the terms “thread-safe class” and “thread-safe program”
>   nearly interchangeably thus far. Is a thread-safe program one that is
>   constructed entirely of thread-safe classes? Not necessarily—a
>   program that consists entirely of thread-safe classes may not be
>   thread-safe, and a thread-safe program may contain classes that are
>   not thread-safe.

- How a thread-safe program may contain classes that are not thread-safe ? additional code example will be really appreciated.

Comment: No class is "safe" or "unsafe" in a vacuum.  If a class is described as "thread safe" that only means that it's own "contract" is maintained regardless of threading, not that an application built around it will "inherit" that safety.

Comment: im reading the same book right now. actually, i understand how a thread-safe program can contain classes that are not thread-safe. however, i don't understand how you can have a program that is not thread-safe but consists entirely of thread-safe classes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two basic cases where that is possible:

1. Non-thread-safe objects are confined to individual threads.
2. Access to shared non-thread-safe objects is externally coordinated by the threads using them.  Extremely simplistic example:  by synchronizing all access with

   ```
       synchronized( sharedObject ) {
           sharedObject.access();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Because local variables are only ever accessed by a single thread, a program could be thread-safe and use local variables whose class is something that would be non-thread-safe in other circumstances.

Comment: Or, in other words, you only need to worry that the instances shared between several threads are thread safe.